# Convergence of a series resembling a geometric one

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I am looking for the convergence value of the following series:

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{r^{2(n-1)}\exp(i(2n-1)\delta)\cos(2n-1)\phi}
\end{equation}

My first approach was to treat it as a geometric one, but, looking at its exponents, I am not sure they can be related.
According to you which is the best way to find its convergence value?
Thank you

Comment: So that it converges, use the comparison test. This will converge when $r < 1$. To actually find the convergence value, I think Fourier series would be the way to go.

Comment: Use $\cos z=(1/2)(e^{iz} + e^{-iz})$ to express it as a sum of two different geometric series.

Comment: Write the cosine term as the real part of a complex exponential, combine the terms as something raised to the $n$, sum the geometric series, which converges when $1<r<1$.  Take the real part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. First, write the cosine term as a sum of two exponentials:
$$\cos(2n-1)\phi=\frac12(e^{i(2n-1)\phi}+e^{-i(2n-1)\phi})$$Then you can write
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{r^{2(n-1)}\exp(i(2n-1)\delta)\cos(2n-1)\phi}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{2n}r^{-1}e^{i2n\delta}e^{-i\delta}e^{i2n\phi}e^{-i\phi}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{2n}r^{-1}e^{i2n\delta}e^{-i\delta}e^{-i2n\phi}e^{i\phi}$$
Now take the factors not depending on $n$ in front of the sums, which will become geometric series of the type $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a^2)^n$$